# cmake target_sources File set TYPE may only be "HEADERS"

Tags: c++, cmake, module

I am using CMake 3.26.0-rc2

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(std_module_example CXX)


set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "3c375311-a3c9-4396-a187-3227ef642046")
if(WIN32)
  include(msvc_modules.cmake)
else()
  include(gcc_modules.cmake)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_library(std_module_example)
target_link_libraries(std_module_example)

target_sources(std_module_example
  PRIVATE
     t4.cxx
  PUBLIC
     FILE_SET cxx_modules TYPE CXX_MODULES FILES
     t1.cxx t2.cxx t3.cxx
)

add_executable(main main.cxx)
target_link_libraries(main std_module_example)
```

I got an error while running cmake:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/gcc-12.2.0/bin/g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (target_sources):
  target_sources File set TYPE may only be "HEADERS"

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

download from :https://gitlab.kitware.com/bill-hoffman/cxx_modules/-/tree/main/std_example

Comment: "I am using CMake 3.26.0-rc2" - But your `cmake_minimum_required` stands that the project is written for CMake 3.23. That is, CMake provides for your project those features, that has been available for 3.23 version. In that version the only possible value for [target_sources](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.23/command/target_sources.html) was HEADERS, and variable `CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API` had no effect: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.23.5/Help/dev/experimental.rst. Looks like you write your `CMakeLists.txt` for CMake 3.25, so you need appropriate VERSION setting.

Answer (score 2):

The `CXX_MODULES` type was introduced into what CMake calls "Experimental features". You enable them by setting a specific value that you can see here:

```
set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "3c375311-a3c9-4396-a187-3227ef642046")
```

These values change **depending on which version of CMake** you use.

Since you state that you are using CMake 3.26.0-rc2 then the value you want is [**located here.**](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.26.0-rc2/Help/dev/experimental.rst)

That is, you need to change the line like so:

```
set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "2182bf5c-ef0d-489a-91da-49dbc3090d2a")
```

And it should work.